# How do you return missing Windows 10 .exe files?

Tags: windows, windows-10

What do you really do in case you no longer have some .exe files that usually come pre-installed with Windows?

I'm talking about files such as notepad.exe, cmd.exe, etc', that usually appear in:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

Is there a menu that installs such files, or any easy way to obtain those files again without having to re-install Windows?

Comment: I'd wonder. *How did they go missing to start with?*

Comment: Have you tried repairing Windows?

Answer (score -1):

Try using on a elevated command prompt 'sfc /scannow'. This command is suppose to restore window system files. It might restore those files you are missing. Either way report back I'm curious.